# Xcode always defaults to building for iPod touch 7, how can this be changed?

Tags: xcode

Platform:
Xcode 13.1
MacOS 11.5.2

Whenever creating a new iOS project, Xcode always sets the simulator type to build to as iPod touch 7.  How can Xcode be made to default to another device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the option key while selecting on the drop down menu.
it works for me on xcode v13.2

Comment: I'm talking about BEFORE you click on the drop down.  Are you saying that once you do this, all subsequent projects will default to the simulator you selected?

Comment: you have to do is once! but every new project still same I think ,couldn't check it right now

Comment: sorry I realized that after reboot it turns back again ipod touch :(

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and holding option only opens the scheme editor.